# only 1 of 2 values displayed on UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uilabel

I want the ServingSize UIlabel on my app to display portion and unit (as in 1 fl. oz.). However, it only displays the unit (so I just see fl. oz.). I don't see what could be going wrong. Below is the relevant code. I declare both portion and unit as NSString* at the top of the .m file. When I NSLog portion after it is assigned, I see the correct value.

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in self.team){
        portion = [dict objectForKey:@"portion"];
        unit = [dict objectForKey:@"unit"];
    }

    self.ServingSize.text = (@"%@ %@", portion, unit);
    self.Servings.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Maybe try NSString stringWithFormat instead of just @"%@ %@"?

Comment: Yes, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", portion, unit]` would be better. If that doesn't work, you should then check the individual fields and make sure both `portion` and `unit` return valid values.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Code ( I posted this answer because it may be helpfull to other)

```
or(NSDictionary *dict in self.team){
        portion = [dict objectForKey:@"portion"];
        unit = [dict objectForKey:@"unit"];
    }

    self.ServingSize.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", portion, unit];
    self.Servings.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```